# How to help Triss finish what she has to do in Novigrad?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am in the middle of the Brother's in arm quest, and tried to recruit Triss. Talking with her, she said she has to finish something first. Now the quest marker is on Triss and the quest description is that I should help her finish what she has to do. Yet I cannot seem to progress a new quest line. I can ask her about her hand, though this is related to a previous quest in the Witch hunter's lair.

Is this quest bugged? Or do I have to get the relevant quest some other way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To fix these issues you can use the console.

If you are stuck at the "Brothers In Arms" quest with Triss, open console and type in the following "below" in this order. It will start a quest that is missing from your game. The quest to find Philippa Eilhart "Redania's Most Wanted". After you complete that quest and turn it in to Radovid, it will trigger "Now or Never, and so on. You game is back on track and fixed.

```
addfact(q302_completed)
addfact(q302_post_mafia_completed)
addfact(sq302_start)
```

Reason the quest gets bugged. After you find Whoreson and complete the quest, you must leave the area through the gate. If you do not, it will not trigger the mission "Redania's Most Wanted" and so on.

There is a mod that lets people fast travel from anywhere and this is what causes the issue for most people. They fast travel out of Whoresons house instead of passing through the gate which of course a ruins a huge chunk of the game.

Comment: I am blocked at the same point, I wrote what you said on the console, but nothing seems to change. What I have to do?

Comment: I can confirm that the above commands trigger that quest, however, when I get to the hideout, there's no quest marker, nor are there any witch hunters.

Comment: Adding this comment I found somewhere else that fixed my issue of having no one to talk to and no quest marker: 

"Figured it out now. I used those commands while I was on Kaer Morhen, so they didn't spawn the NPCs. Loaded another save and put the commands in while I was in Velen. Sorted now!" 

So just load a save without the commands run yet where you're near novigrad and then run the commands in order.

Answer (score 5):

The questline broke to using the [Fast travel everywhere mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/324).

> Apparently, this is because I used the Fast Travel From Anywhere mod
> during the Get Junior quest.
>
> I figure this might be beneficial to others, so I've made a small list
> of quests that will break if you fast-travel out of a building during
> these quests:
>
> Novigrad - Pyres of Novigrad: Do not fast travel out of Triss's house. You won't be able to talk to the beggars or follow the thief.
>
> Novigrad - Get Junior: Do not fast travel out of Junior's mansion.    This
> prevents you from completing a main quest and several 2ndary quests
> including "A Favor for Radovid", "Redania's Most Wanted", "Now or
> Never".
>
> Kaer Morhen - To Bait a Forktail:
> After killing the forktail, you need to race    Eskel down the
> mountain. If you fast travel out of the cave, you'll
> need to go back to meet Eskel.
>
> Basically, the rule of thumb is to avoid using the instant fast travel
> while you're on a mission or in a mission area.

I can confirm that this was the issue as on a 2nd replay I refrained from using fast travel mod in quests, and everything worked as expected.

Source: [www.reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/3lnnon/help_i_cant_start_the_quest_now_or_never_it_just/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already helped her evacuate the mages from Novigrad (Correct me if I'm wrong. That quest is required to recruit her).

So, it looks like there are 2 related quests: [A Matter of Life and Death](http://www.vg247.com/2015/05/15/the-witcher-3-a-matter-of-life-and-death-walkthrough/) and [Now or Never](http://www.vg247.com/2015/05/15/the-witcher-3-now-or-never-walkthrough/). From the quest description, it sounds like on of those are missing. If all of these quests are completed, she should show up at Kaer Morhen automatically when the time is right. But the marker obviously should not be there..

It's likely a bug if those quests are all finished and the marker is still on Triss. If you find that to be the case, you might have to reload an earlier save. You might lose hours of work,depending on how far into the quest you are, but being this far into the game, it's probably worth it if you can reload far enough.
Good luck!

Comment: "Now or Never" _is_ the quest where you evacuate the mages from Novigrad...

Answer (score -2):

Do the side quest for the fox mask. (Buy the outfit don't be a cheap arse) Lol opened up dialog for me with Triss

Comment: If that quest is already done (seems it is), Elihal will don't have a fox mask in his store to sell.

Answer (score -3):

The questline isnt broken. You just have to look in your secondary quests and complete any that have anything to do with Triss. This is the same for all allies that you try to recruit.

Answer (score -3):

You just have to find Albert in the purple panther mask. If you head out of the courtyard towards the man with the dogs in the yard, to the left is a small walkway where i found him talking with a few people.