# Brothers in Arms. Novigrad. Help Triss finish what she has to do. Bug?

Tags: the-witcher-3

It seems there is a bug in Witcher 3. I am not using any mods and I finished all the secondary quests. There are several similar questions on Internet such as this [one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236235/how-to-help-triss-finish-what-she-has-to-do-in-novigrad) where it is asked to enter this on the console:

```
addfact(q302_completed)
addfact(q302_post_mafia_completed)
addfact(sq302_start)
```

I did it, but it doesn't change anything.

So as you can see, I finished all the secondary quests and to get on the boat I need to finish `Brothers in Arms` first.

[image]

When I talk to Triss, I have no quest options.

[image]

What should I do?

[image]

After this I tried to fast travel to Skellige, save and reload the game. But it doesn't change anything.

I also tried this:

```
addfact(q302_whoreson_found)
addfact(q302_post_mafia_completed)
addfact(q302_fdb_spoke_with_radowid_chess_club)
addfact(sq302_start)
addfact(q302_completed)
addfact(q303_completed)
addfact(q303_triss_about_sq301)
addfact(triss_dd_start)
addfact(sq301_started)
```

Comment: This is a common issue when fast traveling out of D's place. These console commands never worked for me, and they are the only resource you'll have to get Triss to finish up this quest.

Comment: So how did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Others got this issue because they installed some mods. I have a vanilla version of Witcher 3 from Steam

Comment: I never got this issue solved, it's been a bug without a proper fix for years. There's no reliable way to start this part of the quest. The good news is, is that you can just keep going with the main quest and the game will just continue. This is an optional quest that only affects one thing.

Comment: The problem is the boat does not want to leave. I don't know why

Comment: Gosh ! You were right, I tried to get on the wrong boat. I can continue the game, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> addfact(q302_whoreson_found) addfact(q302_post_mafia_completed)
>   addfact(q302_fdb_spoke_with_radowid_chess_club) addfact(sq302_start)
>   addfact(q302_completed) addfact(q303_completed)
>   addfact(q303_triss_about_sq301) addfact(triss_dd_start)
>   addfact(sq301_started)

This is a common issue when fast traveling out of D's place. These console commands never worked for me, and they are the only resource you'll have to get Triss to finish up this quest

I never got this issue solved, it's been a bug without a proper fix for years. There's no reliable way to start this part of the quest. The good news is, is that you can just keep going with the main quest and the game will just continue. This is an optional quest that only affects one thing